# c string return type incorrect?

Tags: c, string, return

I have these two functions in my main.c file, but when i try to compile I am getting the following errors:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:30: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
main.c: At top level:
main.c:51: error: conflicting types for ‘getFileString’
main.c:30: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘getFileString’ was here
```

I do not understand why I cannot return the pointer to the string I created inside of the getFileString method. I really need an explination.

I am really lost as to why this is happening any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "tokenizer.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        if(argc != 3){
                printf("not valid # of arguments");
                return 1;
        }
        struct stat info;
        int status;
        status = stat(argv[2], &info);

        if(status != 0){
                printf("Error, errno = %d\n", errno);
                return 1;
        }
        //command line argument is file
        if(S_ISREG (info.st_mode)){
                printf("%s is a file \n", argv[2]);
                char *string1;
                string1  = getFileString(argv[2]);
                printf("string in file is %s", string1);
                free(string1);
                return 0;
        }
        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)){
                printf("%s is a directory \n", argv[2]);
                openDirRec(argv[2]);
                //what to do if command line argument is directory
        }
        return 0;
        /*
           DIR* directory;
           struct dirent* a; 

        //file to write results to 
        FILE *newFile = fopen("results.txt", "w+");
        */

}

char* getFileString(char *fileName){
        FILE* qp;
        qp = fopen(fileName, "r");
        char ch;
        int sizeCheck = 0;
        while((ch=fgetc(qp))!=EOF){
                sizeCheck++;
        }
        fclose(qp);
        if(sizeCheck == 0){
                return NULL;
        }
        else{
                char *fileString;
                fileString = malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeCheck + 1);

                FILE *cp;
                cp = fopen(fileName, "r");
                char cj;
                int count = 0;
                while((cj=fgetc(cp)!=EOF)){
                        fileString[count] = cj;
                        count++;
                }
                fileString[sizeCheck + 1] = '\0';
                return fileString;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare functions before you use them.  Because you used `getFileString()` before declaring it, the compiler inferred the types of the arguments from the actual arguments used, and implicitly gave it the return type `int`.  Then when the compiler encounters your definition later, it notes that the return types `int` and `char *` don't match, hence the error.

(This also explains the warning `main.c:30: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` -- you were assigning an `int`, or what the compiler decided was an `int` because you hadn't told it otherwise, to a `char *`.)

Add this line before your `main()` function to declare the function:

```
char* getFileString(char *fileName);
```

Alternatively, you can move the entire function definition before `main()`.

(You technically only need to pre-declare functions if there is a circular dependency between them, otherwise you can just order functions such that no function is used before it is defined.  However, for code organization purposes sometimes it makes more sense to declare all of your functions at the top and implement them later.)

---

As a side note, always compile with the maximum warning level your compiler allows (`-Wall` on gcc).  The compiler would have issued a warning that it hadn't seen a declaration for `getFileString()` and that it was generating an implicit one.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still kinda a noob at c but it works perfectly now.

Comment: actually im having one other little problem as well when the string prints out in the command line im getting a bunch of weird characters that look like hex numbers in boxes any idea what this could be?

Comment: @atg963 Usually that means you are trying to display something as a string, but it hasn't been initialized and so it contains garbage.